# Plotting fast incoming data in a rolling window

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, time-series

I try to plot fast data (1-10 data points per second) with matplotlib in a rolling window.

I like pandas because it's simple.

My questions are:

1. Is my framework efficient (with regard to using pandas, matplotlib's "plt.draw")?
2. If the loop runs for say 1'000'000'000 times, will the data frame (self.df) become too large --> Is it better to delete the data collector at some point and then start with an empty data frame? But what about the continuity of the rolling window then?
3. The example starts to get very slow after a while. Is it because of the inefficient plotting or because of the inefficient use of memory
4. The console shows a Warning:

> MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: Using default event loop until function
>   specific to this GUI is implemented warnings.warn(str, mplDeprecation)

Do I have to take care of that?

Thanks in advance

Here is what I have so far:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt; plt.ion()
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
plt.style.use('ggplot')
from pathlib import Path
import datetime
import matplotlib


class tradeScreen(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.rollingWindow = 100
        self.df = pd.DataFrame(dict(time=np.NaN, bid=np.NaN, ask=np.NaN, limitBuy=np.NaN, limitSell=np.NaN, stopLoss=np.NaN), index=np.arange(self.rollingWindow))
        self.df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(self.df['time'])  # format 'time' as datetime object

        # initialise plot and line
        plt.figure()
        G = gridspec.GridSpec(2, 1)

        self.axes_1 = plt.subplot(G[0, :])
        self.axes_1.set_ylabel('First Panel')

        self.axes_2 = plt.subplot(G[1, :])
        self.axes_2.set_ylabel('Second Panel')

        self.line1, = self.axes_1.plot(self.df['time'], self.df['bid'])
        self.line2, = self.axes_1.plot(self.df['time'], self.df['ask'])
        self.line3, = self.axes_1.plot(self.df['time'], self.df['limitBuy'])
        self.line4, = self.axes_1.plot(self.df['time'], self.df['limitSell'])
        self.line5, = self.axes_2.plot(self.df['time'], self.df['stopLoss'])


    def plotter(self, tick, i):

        df = self.df
        rollingWindow = self.rollingWindow

        current_time = pd.datetime.now()

        df.loc[i, "bid"] = tick["bid"].values.item(0)
        df.loc[i, "ask"] = tick["ask"].values.item(0)
        df.loc[i, "limitBuy"] = tick["limitBuy"].values.item(0)
        df.loc[i, "limitSell"] = tick["limitSell"].values.item(0)
        df.loc[i, "stopLoss"] = tick["stopLoss"].values.item(0)
        df.loc[i, "time"] = current_time

        self.line1.set_data(pd.to_datetime(df['time'][:i].tail(rollingWindow)), df['bid'][:i].tail(rollingWindow))
        self.line2.set_data(pd.to_datetime(df['time'][:i].tail(rollingWindow)), df['ask'][:i].tail(rollingWindow))
        self.line3.set_data(pd.to_datetime(df['time'][:i].tail(rollingWindow)), df['limitBuy'][:i].tail(rollingWindow))
        self.line4.set_data(pd.to_datetime(df['time'][:i].tail(rollingWindow)), df['limitSell'][:i].tail(rollingWindow))
        self.line5.set_data(pd.to_datetime(df['time'][:i].tail(rollingWindow)), df['stopLoss'][:i].tail(rollingWindow))

        self.axes_1.autoscale_view(True, True, True)
        self.axes_1.relim()
        self.axes_2.autoscale_view(True, True, True)
        self.axes_2.relim()

        plt.draw()
        plt.pause(0.00000000000000001)


p = tradeScreen()
i = 0
for i in np.arange(300):

    # generate random data point
    t = pd.datetime.now()
    bid = np.random.rand()
    ask = np.random.rand()
    limitBuy = np.random.rand()
    limitSell = np.random.rand()
    stopLoss = np.random.rand()

    tick = pd.DataFrame(dict(time=t, bid=bid, ask=ask, limitBuy=limitBuy, limitSell=limitSell, stopLoss=stopLoss),
                        index=np.arange(1))

    p.plotter(tick, i)
    i += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look at the `Animation` module to make animations in `matplotlib`. See this link for explanations: http://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2012/08/18/matplotlib-animation-tutorial/

For posterity, the first example on that page, which gives the gist of the `Animation` system is:

```
"""
Matplotlib Animation Example

author: Jake Vanderplas
email: vanderplas@astro.washington.edu
website: http://jakevdp.github.com
license: BSD
Please feel free to use and modify this, but keep the above information. Thanks!
"""

import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation

# First set up the figure, the axis, and the plot element we want to animate
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(xlim=(0, 2), ylim=(-2, 2))
line, = ax.plot([], [], lw=2)

# initialization function: plot the background of each frame
def init():
    line.set_data([], [])
    return line,

# animation function.  This is called sequentially
def animate(i):
    x = np.linspace(0, 2, 1000)
    y = np.sin(2 * np.pi * (x - 0.01 * i))
    line.set_data(x, y)
    return line,

# call the animator.  blit=True means only re-draw the parts that have changed.
anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init,
                               frames=200, interval=20, blit=True)
```

using blitting (`blit=True` on that last line) might improve your performances.
However, AFAIK matplotlib was not designed with performance in mind, and you could look into other libraries more suited for this task, such as [PyQtGraph](http://www.pyqtgraph.org/)

Comment: Hi Diziet, many thanks for your reply. When I run the code it only returns some error message File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\animation.py", line 898, in _blit_clear
    a.figure.canvas.restore_region(bg_cache[a])
KeyError: <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x00000000044C4748>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backend_bases.py", line 1305, in _on_timer...